# GitLab on Azure, could not resolve host

Tags: git, azure, ssh, gitlab, azure-virtual-machine

I've installed GitLab on Azure according to this:
http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/azure/index.html

And now have a new VM running on mygit.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com, with ports 22, 80 and 443 open. I can log in to my GitLab through the link above.

Locally I've set up the following:

```
git config --global user.name "Me My"
git config --global user.email "me.my@i.com"
```

As well as ssh stuff according to https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

I've created a project (inside a group) in my GitLab repository, but then, whatever I try, cloning or pushing existing code, over SSH or HTTP, I get the following error messages:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab-ce.blablabla.cx.internal.cloudapp.net:MyGroup/MyProject.git: Name or service not known
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

And

> fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ce.blablabla.cx.internal.cloudapp.net:MyGroup/MyProject.git/': Could not resolve host: gitlab-ce.blablabla.cx.internal.cloudapp.net

What could I be missing? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To clarify:  Have you referred to the link :https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/
You also need to configure your external URL for gitlab, see here: http://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html

Comment: If your GitLab server is misbehaving try running "sudo gitlab-ctl restart" before anything else.,

Comment: Will check both of these tomorrow when I'm back at work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What could I be missing? Any help would be appreciated!

In Azure, Gitlab is **pre-configured**, so that `external_url` is a example, not an existing address, we should change it to your domain name.

We find the **external_url** here: `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`
Change it from `http://gitlab-ce.hxakzvpf0otezeojz3wqhme5wg.cx.internal.cloudapp.net` to your VM's domain name(we can find it via Azure portal), like this:

[image]

Then RUN `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` for the change to take effect.

Now, we can refresh the browser to get new http address, like this:

[image]

Then we can use this new address to pull or clone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm having trouble SSHing in to change the URL. Will verify as soon as possible